# OSB12c - Rest proxy service throwing Translation error in case of invalid JSON input

Tags: osb

We have configured REST proxy service that accepts JSON input. If the input is not a well formed JSON OSB is throwing Translation error with HTTP 500 Staus code. Is that possible we can send Customized error message in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a global error handler for your pipeline and set the desired error message using a replace action here, followed by a "Reply" action. 
 
Keep in mind that if you try to "read" the original request body in the global error handler, and if the original request was malformed, it will get thrown up to the system error handler and you will get the system error message again.

Here's a sample OSB 12.2.1.1 project you can use to try this: https://github.com/jvsingh/SOATestingWithCitrus/tree/develop/OSB/Samples/ServiceBusApplication1

The [accompanying soapui project](https://github.com/jvsingh/SOATestingWithCitrus/tree/develop/OSB/Samples/ServiceBusApplication1/soapui) contains two requests. The malformed request should return this:
[image]
(I have only set the response here. You would also need to set the proper content type and decide whether you want to treat this as "success" or "failure" etc. in the reply action)